# Calculate percentage of values above a threshold in a group with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data set and would like to get the share of values (`V2`) that are above a certain threshold (in this case lets assume 24 so all values above that should count) based on groups (`V1`).

```
V1   V2
 A   25
 A   23
 A   25
 B   25
 B   25
 C   15
 C   15
 D   0
 D   0
```

The results should look like this:

```
V1   share
A    0.666
B    1.0
C    0
D    0
```

Ideally, I would like to perform this calculation in `data.table`

Comment: `dt[, mean(V2 >= 24), by = V1]`

Comment: After checking, this solved my problem, thanks! Please post it as a solution so I can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `mean` of the number of `V2` over the threshold by `V1`

```
# Data
V1 <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D")
V2 <- c(25, 23, 25, 25, 25,  15, 15, 0, 0)
dt <- data.table(V1, V2)

 dt[, .(share = mean(V2 >= 24)), by = V1]

#   V1     share
#1:  A 0.6666667
#2:  B 1.0000000
#3:  C 0.0000000
#4:  D 0.0000000
```